# preimage of a closed set under continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, continuity, solution-verification

We have the following statement:

> Let be $f$ a continuous function. The preimage of a closed set is again a closed set.

Let be $f:(0,\infty)\times [0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ where $f(x,y)=x+y$.

(Where "$[$" means that $0$ is included and "$($" means that $0$ is excluded).

If I consider the preimage $f^{-1}(1)$ or in other words $D:=\{(x,y)\in (0,\infty)\times [0,\infty)\mid f(x,y)=1\}$ then this would mean that it is closed. However, it is easy to construct a counter-example to see that not all limit points of $D$ are an element of $D$ (e.g. the limit point $(0,1)$). So $D$ can't be a closed set.

How is this possible? Where is my mistake?

Comment: Please write the preimage ("if I consider the preimage") as $f^{-1}(\{1\})$, or, more casually, as $f^{-1}(1)$.

Answer (score 1):

The set $D$, which is equal to$$\{(x,y)\in(0,\infty)\times[0,\infty)\mid x+y=1\}=\{(x,1-x)\mid x\in(0,1]\},$$is a closed subset of $(0,\infty)\times[0,\infty)$. In fact, it is *not* a closed subset of $\Bbb R^2$, but that's not relevant here.

Comment: I had a typo regarding my limit point counter-example. Please see my edit. How is it possible that $D$ is closed?

Comment: Because $D=\bigl((0,\infty)\times[0,\infty)\bigr)\cap\{(x,1-x)\mid x\in\Bbb R\}$. That is, it is the intersection of a closed subset of $\Bbb R^2$ ($\{(x,1-x)\mid x\in\Bbb R\}$) with $(0,\infty)\times[0,\infty)$; therefore, it is a closed subset of $(0,\infty)\times[0,\infty)$.

Comment: Ah o.k. I got a bit confused which superset we are referrring to. If $(0,\infty)\times [0,\infty)$ is the superset then my counter-example doesn't apply as the point $(0,1)\neq \{(0,\infty)\times [0,\infty)\}$. However, if we refer to the superset $\mathbb{R}^2$ then my counter-example does apply and $D$ is not closed. Actually, this was the case I had in mind when I asked the question because this contradicts the given statement. So I still don't understand why the statement I made in the question is wrong in this case.

Comment: Which statement? When you say that $D$ is not a closed set?

Comment: The statement at the beginnning of my question.

Comment: Do you mean “The preimage of a closed set is again a closed set.”?

Comment: Yes, exactly this is the statement I am referring to.

Comment: But the statement is *not* wrong! As I have explained in my answer, $f^{-1}(1)$ **is** a closed subset of $(0,\infty)\times[0,\infty)$.

Comment: But it is not a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and that is what I don't understand because the statement makes this claim.

Comment: No, it does **not**. It claims that it is a closed subset of the domain of $f$, which, in your case, is $(0,\infty)\times[0,\infty)$. And $f^{-1}(1)$ **is** a closed subset of that set.

Comment: Ok, then there is a mistake in our lecture notes because there it refers to a superset of the domain of $f$, e.g. $\mathbb{R}^2$, and this superset doesn't have to be the domain.